# How to display UIScrollView scrollbar/s permanently instead of just flashing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, interface-builder

The app I am building for an iPad has multiple text fields. So I had to use a scrollview. I would like to display the scrollbar/s permanently so that the user knows there are some more fields at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

As far I'm aware, it's not possible to permanently show the scrollbar.

Apple recommends to flash the scrollbar using:

```
[theScrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, this is simply not possible. Momentarily flashing the scrollbar informs the user additional contend is available, just like other applications do. User are accustomed to this behavior.